# Query & generic

Tags: c#, sql, generics, param, dbproviderfactories

I'm developing a C# solution with data access to Oracle.

And would like to have a generic solution about query.

Here is a part of my code :

```
public DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OracleClient");

    using (DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            DbConnectionStringBuilder csb = factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder();
            csb["Data Source"] = @"Northwind";
            csb["User Id"] = @"Northwind";
            csb["Password"] = @"Northwind";

            conn.ConnectionString = csb.ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();

            using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;

                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    DbDataAdapter da = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And I call my method like this :

```
DataAccess.Provider data = new DataAccess.Provider();
DataTabel dt = dt.GetData("select * from myTable);
```

This works pretty good but this is not my aim.

I have a second class called `CL_mpg` with all my SQL queries.

```
class CL_MPG
{
    public string rq_sql;

    public string selectParam(string param)
    {
        this.rq_sql = "select * from myTable where id = '" + param + "';";
        return this.rq_sql;
    }

    public string select()
    {
        this.rq_sql = "select * from myTable";
        return this.rq_sql;
    }

    //...

}
```

And I would like to use my methods `selectParam` and/or `select` to fill my datatable, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Any reason you're rolling your own DAL, as opposed to using a pre-existing framework?

Comment: I cant use framework, school project

Comment: @Shrimp yet you are using the BCL (the .NET Framework) classes... why draw an arbitrary line? Also: *parameters*; never concatenate values into SQL. If you learn **one thing** this term, learn this.

Comment: And what should i do ?

Comment: Additional thoughts: having a method which returns the string it assigns to a field is... odd; it looks like it should do one or the other (I'd say doing the `return` only is a better idea); and `select` is a contextual keyword - worth avoiding.

Comment: @Shrimp "what should I do"... design how you want it to work, then implement that. Write code of how you intend it to work, even if it doesn't actually compile etc yet. It is unclear to me what your actual question is here. What question do you want us to answer?

Comment: Aim of the project : generic solution to create datatable and return it, fill with the good query. That's why I want to use "pre-made" query and use it as parameter to fill my datatable, but i'm kinda lost, actually I can do : DataAccess.Provider data = new DataAccess.Provider();
DataTabel dt = dt.GetData("the query I want"); and it works fine but I had to write manually, how can i made it simply ?

Answer (score 0):

Although others complain at your learning attempt, everyone has to start somewhere. Your method is actually an ok start, but I would change the parameter from a string to a DbCommand object.  Then, you can create your methods to properly build the command and set proper parameters.  Then pass the entire prepared command to your wrapper method (that creates connection, tests open successful, queries data, etc) and have your method return a DataTable object as you have... something like

```
public class CL_MPG
{
   private DataTable GetData(DbCommand cmd )
   {   
      // do all the same as you have with exception of your USING DBCOMMAND.
      // just set the connection property of the incoming command to that of
      // your connection created
      // AT THIS PART -- 
      // using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
      // {
      //    cmd.CommandText = query;
      // just change to below and remove the closing curly bracket for using dbcommand
      cmd.Connection = conn;
   }

   // Now, your generic methods that you want to expose for querying
   // something like
   public DataTable GetAllData()
   {
      DbCommand cmd = new DbCommand( "select * from YourTable" );
      return GetData( cmd );
   }

   public DataTable GetUser( int someIDParameter )
   {
      DbCommand cmd = new DbCommand( "select * from YourTable where ID = @parmID" );
      cmd.Parameters.Add( "@parmID", someIDParameter );
      return GetData( cmd );
   }

   public DataTable FindByLastName( string someIDParameter )
   {
      DbCommand cmd = new DbCommand( "select * from YourTable where LastName like @parmTest" );
      cmd.Parameters.Add( "@parmTest", someIDParameter );
      return GetData( cmd );
   }
}
```

Notice the command is being built and fully prepared and parameterized vs concatination of strings as prior comment was made which could expose you to SQL-injection.  As for the parameters, and not querying Oracle, they may need to be tweaked some.  Different engines use slightly different conventions.  If connecting to SQL-Server database, it uses "@" to identify a parameter.  In SyBase Advantage Database, it uses ":".  Using Visual FoxPro, a simple "?" placeholder is used.

Also, if your query has many criteria, just keep adding additional "@parm" type placeholders, then add your parameters in the same order as they appear in your query just to make sure you didn't miss any.  Some functions could have none, one or more based on your needs.  Then, in the samples provided, its as simple as doing something like

```
DataTable whoIs = yourCL_MPGObject.GetUser( 23 );
if( whoIs.Rows.Count > 0 )
   MessageBox.Show( whoIs.Rows[0]["WhateverColumnName"] );
```